# C# Generic Type Constraints

Tags: c#, generics, methods, type-constraints

I have never used generics before and was wondering how to constrain the Type to either `Double[]` or `List<Double>` (or if this is even the correct thing to do). I need to calculate the average of many numbers that are sometimes known in advance (i.e. I can create an array of exact size) but, at other times, are generated immediately before the calculation (i.e. I use a List).

I would like this generic method `Average(T arrayOrList)` to be able to accept an array or list instead of overloading the `Average()` method.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can use LINQ, there's already an `Average()` method that is overloaded for the numeric types.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I can't use LINQ, using .NET 2.0 but I never thought of simply using IEnumerable<double>. Never send an ME to do a CSci's job... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since both `double[]` and `List<double>` implement `IEnumerable<double>`, I'd suggest the following:

```
public double Average(IEnumerable<double> arrayOrList) {
    // use foreach to loop through arrayOrList and calculate the average
}
```

That's simple subtype polymorphism, no generics required.

As others have already mentioned, if you simply want to calculate an average, [such a method already exists in the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946.aspx).

Comment: A follow-up question, what would be the best way to determine if the `arrayOrList` is an array or a list? I thought of making an `is` check for each case in an if-else branch but was just wondering if perhaps there was a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Jon: If you really need different code for array and list, the "correct" solution would be to create two overloads `Average(double[])` and `Average(List<double>)`. That way, you don't need any dynamic type checks at all. If you have common code, put that in a third (private) method that accepts an `IEnumerable<double>`, which is called by both of your overloads. Note that, if you just want to calculate the average, you don't need to determine if it's an array or a list.

Comment: Thanks Heinzi, your answer worked great for the average method but I have another that requires me to sort the array. I am using .NET 2.0 so I can't use `Enumerable.OrderBy<>()` so I was looking for the best way to convert it back to either an array or list and then sort it. But it sounds like overloading the method may be the preferred way?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, overloading sounds like the correct solution. In particular, since there are already specific methods in the .net Framework (even 2.0) for sorting an array (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aw9s5t8f.aspx) and a list (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

I would just use `IEnumerable<double>`, since all you need to do is loop over the data (and both lists and arrays support this, as do deferred sequences).

In fact, Microsoft got there first:

```
var avg = sequence.Average();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Why not just write a function that accepts an `IEnumerable<double>`?

Then if you really want to use an `ArrayList`, I assume not by choice you can use the `AsEnumerable()` extensions.

EDIT, seems I miread ArrayOrList, but the answer still applies, although it was 56 secs late

Answer (score 0):

var x = new List();
var average = x.Average();
var y = new Double[10];
var average = y.Average();